# Can I save custom variable/id in paypal transaction?

Tags: paypal

For now the flow looks like this: mobile app performs paypal payment and when it is complete it sends information about transaction to backend API. Then backend API makes request to paypal API and check transaction. What I need is to somehow "mark" transaction to identify it later. Is it possible to send some custom variable/id when making payment (on IOS) and then retrieve it by transaction id?

Comment: Is this for Payments Standard or Payments Pro?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure for now we are using dev (fake) paypal API - whats the difference between Standard and Pro?

Comment: There's no API for standard (it's HTML form based with PayPal handling checkout). It sounds like you're using Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to specify a payment for an order. one is the `invoice` field and the other is `custom`. Both will be passed back to you via [paypal-ipn](/questions/tagged/paypal-ipn) or in your request for information about the transaction ID.

Comment: How I can set those fields using IOS SDK? I can't found this in docs https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/PayPalMobile/PayPalPayment.h

Comment: @user606521 we posted an update to the PayPal iOS SDK this week. Follow [your link to `PayPalPayment.h`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/PayPalMobile/PayPalPayment.h) again, and look for the properties `invoiceNumber` and `custom`.